# What's the difference between onclick events of buttons and divs?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, contenteditable

First of all, this might only apply to Firefox, but I am not sure. Let's start with some code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Editor</title>
    <!-- styling -->
</head>
<body>
    <button id="bold" onclick="executeAction('bold')"  >
        Bold
    </button>
    <div id="italic"  onclick="executeAction('italic')">
        Italic
    </div>
    <div id="editor" contentEditable="true">
        Editor
    </div>
    <script>
        function executeAction(actionName) {
            console.log(actionName);
            var sup = document.queryCommandSupported(actionName);
            console.log(sup);
            var res = document.execCommand(actionName, false, "");
            console.log(res);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So here's the interesting part: Note that *bold* is a *button* while *italic* is a *div*. Both commands are supported as can be checked in the console log or by changing one of the actions, so this is the only difference. However, the *button* does what it was supposed to do (it changes selected text in the "editor" to bold) while the *div* does not.

The console log shows that *execCommand* executed from the *div* returns false, which, according to documentation, is actually a very detailed error message saying "something went wrong and we couldn't be bothered to tell you more".

Sadly, even with all the information I get, I can't figure out why the elements behave differently. Is one of the events actually executed asynchronously? Do buttons get special privileges that other elements have to request first? Does the editing API check where it was executed from to make sure there's a "good" UI?

Comment: `div` "steals" the focus from the selection before the handler is called, while `button` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both the cases the function is executed properly. I think this is what might happen:

1. When you click the `button`, the selection of text is not lost and hence the effect is applied.
2. When you click the `div`, the selection is lost before the call of the function hence the effect is not applied.